# List of gmail atom available labels

Tags: gmail, atom-feed

I use 'Atom' feeds to read the content of gmail at the address
https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/*name* where *name* is either empty (to check the inbox) or a user-defined label (even nested). To parse the result, it is useful to read the XML field `fullcount`, which gives the number of unread messages. With Gmail internal labels, like `starred`, `important`, `sent`, `trash`, `drafts`, `spam`, `all`, however, the `fullcount` is always 0. I recently discovered [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/GRn5j7ND_EI) that for the `important` label one should use the less intuitive name `^iim`. With `^iim` the `fullcount` is set correctly ! Does anyone know if there is a complete list of such labels available ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are called system labels and the [Gmail Content Provider in Android](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/com/google/android/gm/contentprovider/GmailContract.Labels.LabelCanonicalNames#CANONICAL_NAME_SPAM) documents a few:

- ALL_MAIL ^all
- DRAFTS ^r
- INBOX ^i
- INBOX_CATEGORY_FORUMS ^sq_ig_i_group
- INBOX_CATEGORY_PRIMARY ^sq_ig_i_personal
- INBOX_CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS ^sq_ig_i_promo
- INBOX_CATEGORY_SOCIAL ^sq_ig_i_social
- INBOX_CATEGORY_UPDATES ^sq_ig_i_notification
- PRIORITY_INBOX ^iim
- SENT ^f
- SPAM ^s
- STARRED ^t
- TRASH ^k

Comment: Thank you very much ! And also thank you for mentioning Google Developers that I did not know before.